# How do I shorten this generic list?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

My question is simply: how can I shorten this code even more?

```
 List<Button> buttonList = new List<Button>();

        buttonList.Add(button1);
        buttonList.Add(button2);
        buttonList.Add(button3);
        buttonList.Add(button4);
        buttonList.Add(button5);
        buttonList.Add(button6);
        buttonList.Add(button7);
        buttonList.Add(button8);
        buttonList.Add(button9);
```

Comment: You can use a Collection Initializer (search for it).

Comment: It depends on where these buttons are located, are they just variables or are they in a `Panel` of some sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've got your buttons stored in some control's [`Controls`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) collection (say, a `Form` or a `Panel`), then you could use:

```
//here `this` is supposed to be a `Form`
List<Button> buttonList = this.Controls.OfType<Button>() 
                                       .OrderBy(b=>b.Name)
                                       .ToList();
```

In this case you may have your method, returning an enumerable of buttons, stored within some container control:

```
public IEnumerable<Button> GetButtons()
{
    return this.Controls.OfType<Button>().OrderBy(b => b.Name);
    //return this.panel1.Controls.OfType<Button>().OrderBy(b => b.Name);
    //actually any container control you're having your buttons within
}
```

and you may use it:

```
foreach(Button b in GetButtons())
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Great! so I simply create a controls selection ... then return it with an extension method which will then enable me to use for each statements? It's hard to read the code you've written cause I'm still new, but I'm sure I'll get my head around it in the near future :)

Comment: To create an extension method, you need to have a separate static class (here `Extensions`). In that class you write the extension method. Read more [Extension Methods (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx). Since that you may find the extension method (here `GetButtons`) in a method list of any `Control`.

Comment: @GlenHunter if it is not that easy you may use a simple method..I'll update my answer in a moment

Comment: Haha! Yeah, many words that your wrote in your code, I've never heard of before... so just playing catch up  :)

Answer (score 2):

Try a [collection initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx):

```
List<Button> buttonList = new List<Button>() 
{    
     button1,
     button2,
     button3,
     button4,
     button5,
     button6,
     button7,
     button8,
     button9
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [collection initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx):

```
var buttonList = new List<Button>
{
   button1, button2, button3,
   //...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a collection intializer:

```
List<Button> buttonList = new List<Button>
{
    button1,
    button2,
    button3,
    button4,
    button5,
    button6,
    button7,
    button8,
    button9,
}
```