# How do I call a generic list from a private class?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I put a generic list in a private helper method...

```
    private void addButton()
    {
        List<Button> buttonList = new List<Button>();

        buttonList.Add(button1);
        buttonList.Add(button2);
        buttonList.Add(button3);
        buttonList.Add(button4);
        buttonList.Add(button5);
        buttonList.Add(button6);
        buttonList.Add(button7);
        buttonList.Add(button8);
        buttonList.Add(button9); 
    }
```

I know to call this method you have to do something like this...

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            addButton();

            foreach (button in addButton())
            {
                button.Enabled = false;
            }
    }
```

however... when I try to call button in addButton() red lines appear underneath 'button' saying that it could not be found. Please can someone help :)

Comment: that sure is a long way of setting button.Enabled to false why not just write a simple foreach loop on Controls and set it that way checking if object type is of TButton, then set enabled to false..?

Comment: I will also use other functions, such as changing the color and text fields for the button =) The code I originally shown, is hell of a lot of shorter than what I did the first time round. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method should return the list:

```
private List<Button> addButton()
{
    List<Button> buttonList = new List<Button>();

    buttonList.Add(button1);
    //...
    return buttonList;
}
```

Also you don't need the first `addButton();`:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        foreach (Button button in addButton())
        {
            button.Enabled = false;
        }
}
```

And I would have this method rewritten with [yield](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) keyword:

```
private IEnumerable<Button> addButton()
{
    yield return button1;
    yield return button2;
    //...
    yield return button9;
}
```

as you do not need to create a list of buttons just to go through them each time you need to. It's enough just to enumerate them.

---

Also review [Methods (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), section about methods returning values:

> Methods can return a value to the caller. If the return type, the type
>   listed before the method name, is not void, then the method can return
>   the value using the return keyword. A statement with the keyword
>   return followed by a value that matches the return type will return
>   that value to the method caller. The return keyword also stops the
>   execution of the method. If the return type is void, a return
>   statement with no value is still useful to stop the execution of the
>   method. Without the return keyword, the method will stop executing
>   when it reaches the end of the code block. Methods with a non-void
>   return type are required to use the return keyword to return a value.

---

P.S.: review my answer in [How do I shorten this generic list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14491982/how-do-i-shorten-this-generic-list/14492046#14492046). Probably this would still be a better approach?

Comment: Have you changed the return type of the method? You had `void` there, while it has to be `List<Button>` to work.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't notice. Thanks for your help! Very quick =) So if I add the IEnumerable and just add a few yield return button1, button2 9 etc... then it should fill in the gaps? also what does yield mean? Sorry for so many questions... :)

Comment: Glen you should read what the `void` means and read how to `return` a value from a Method..

Comment: @GlenHunter I've added links about programming methods and the `yield` keyword into my answer. Please review them. However they all lead to MSDN. So you can easily find there almost anything.

Comment: Ok great! Thanks so much for your help! I'll read over them now! =)

Comment: @GlenHunter Enjoy reading))

Comment: I wouldn't introduce the yield keyword to a programmer working on return types.

Comment: I just checked, yield in this context, is basically telling the compiler that the code block is an iterator block?

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey you must be right. Well at least, there is an easier variant in the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
private List<Button> addButton()
{
    List<Button> buttonList = new List<Button>();

    buttonList.Add(button1);
    buttonList.Add(button2);
    buttonList.Add(button3);
    buttonList.Add(button4);
    buttonList.Add(button5);
    buttonList.Add(button6);
    buttonList.Add(button7);
    buttonList.Add(button8);
    buttonList.Add(button9); 

    return buttonList;
}


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     foreach (var button in addButton())
     {
          button.Enabled = false;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this -

```
    List<Button> buttonList;
    private List<Button> addButton()
    {
        buttonList = new List<Button>();

        buttonList.Add(button1);
        buttonList.Add(button2);
        buttonList.Add(button3);
        buttonList.Add(button4);
        buttonList.Add(button5);
        buttonList.Add(button6);
        buttonList.Add(button7);
        buttonList.Add(button8);
        buttonList.Add(button9);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        addButton();

        foreach (button in buttonList)
        {
            button.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```